# How can I reset the index in a .groupby output?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe. I want to group the name and brand columns by their respective unique values.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BTSS.png)

I wrote the following python code to group them:

```
high_products = products.reset_index().groupby(['name', 'brand'])[['name', 'brand', 'count_name']]
```

and printed the output with the following code:

```
high_products.head().sort_values(by='count_name', ascending=False)
```

[grouped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyXew.png)

As you can see from the image above, it appears that it is grouping them also based on the index. In the end, I just want to get the unique name and brand values and their respective count names.

How can I do this with .groupby?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line of your code to (count aggregation on name, brand):

```
high_products = products.groupby(['name', 'brand']).agg(['count']).reset_index()
```

Comment: When I do this I get an: 
Attribute error: 'DataFrameGroupBy'object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Comment: @AlejandroL Please use _reset_index()_ function after _agg()_.